# Build an xcode text to speech application

Tags: ios, xcode, native, text-to-speech, native-code

I am building a project that involves creating a mobile app in xcode. The idea is that a user can click a button/menu item and the app will read out what is on the button/menu item. Essentially it is an app for those who have difficulty with their eyesight and require confirmation on what has been pressed.

For example if the button/menu item said "hello there" on it by clicking the button/menu item it would read out "hello there" so the user could hear it.

As mentioned it is been built using xcode and I am aware of AVSpeechSynthesizer. All i can find online are tutorials that either translate your speech or require the user to type in what they want reading out.

Any tips on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

iOS applications automatically read many screen elements when VoiceOver is enabled on your device. If you have custom elements on screen that you want it to read in a particular way, you'll need to investigate the usage of `UIAccessibility`.

Answer (score 0):

AVSpeechSynthesizer can certainly read out whatever text you want it to, the user doesn't need to type anything in. Share some code that uses it and we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

No need for you to reinvent that wheel iOS already supports this behavior look into UIAccessibility.

For example to make a button conform to UIAccessibility you need just one line of code.

```
[button setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"Your Name Here", nil)];
```

and to set a hint

```
[button setAccessibilityHint:NSLocalizedString(@"Your Hint Here", nil)];
```

hope that helps -- seems like you can take today off ;)

and if you are not sure how to use Accessibility on your device visit this link -- http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5018